# Смена названия базы данных

Tags: mongodb

Как переименовать БД в 4.0+ mongodump и mongorestore не работают по той причине, что mongorestore не может восстановить БД, название которой длиннее, чем у исходной.

Т.е. если я сделал дамп из БД, длина названия которой k символов, то восстановить её в БД, длина которой p>k символом — нельзя. Вылетает ошибка, связанная с проблемами восстановления индексов.

Comment: Без коррекции индексов никак. Проще "перелить" одну базу в другую с новым именем, чем сделать то чего Вы хотите имхо...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич ручками переливать, через find, insert?

Comment: Попробуйте залить  дамп с ключем --noIndexRestore

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это, конечно, да, можно. А как с индексами потом быть? Как мне их вытащить из дампа? Или только ручками, из БД? Вы не знаете, почему такие проблемы возникают с монгой?